Do the matrices $\begin{bmatrix} a& a\\a & a \end{bmatrix}$, where $a\in\Bbb R^*$, form a group under multiplication?

Do the 2x2 matrices $\begin{bmatrix} a& a\\a & a \end{bmatrix}$, where $a\ne 0$ is a real number, form a group under multiplication operation of matrices?

We know that if determinant is zero, then matrix can't be inverted, then those kind of matrices don't form groups. The problem is in my textbook, also tells us to prove that the inverted version of the matrices of this form is $\begin{bmatrix}\tfrac{1}{4a} & \tfrac{1}{4a}\\\tfrac{1}{4a} & \tfrac{1}{4a}\end{bmatrix}$ How is this possible? The given identity matrix is
$\begin{bmatrix}\tfrac{1}{2} & \tfrac{1}{2}\\\tfrac{1}{2} & \tfrac{1}{2}\end{bmatrix}$

Have you tried multiplying the given identity by a general matrix of the sort given?  Do you get that matrix back?  I do.  Then multiply the given inverse by your matrix and note that you get the identity.  You have verified the definition of a group.

You say "We know that if determinant is zero, then matrix can't be inverted" That means that if the determinant is zero, there is no matrix such that the product is the usual identity. Here you are given a different identity.

@lulu The product given is the usual product of matrices.

@lulu I’m pretty sure the product is standard. It’s just the identity that’s not. You can just verify that by a direct calculation. (Or note that $\begin{pmatrix} 1/2 & 1/2 \ 1/2 & 1/2 \end{pmatrix}$ is a projection and everything’s just a multiple of that.)

I would encourage you to post your own answer to this! If I were tackling this problem, I would abbreviate the matrices as $[a]$, and using the usual rules for matrix multiplication, $[a]*[b]=[2ab]$, where $a,b$ are non-zero real numbers and $2ab$ is the usual multiplication in $\mathbb{R}$. You do in fact get a group under this operation!

@Barri I wouldn't use $*$ for the multiplication since that would suggest a new operation is being used. But it is the usual matrix multiplication.

"Those kinds of matrices don't have an inverse." That's only true if the identity is the usual identity matrix. But the identity here is $a=\frac12.$

This is similar to how, in the ring $\mathbb Z/6\mathbb Z,$ the elements ${2,4}$ form a group under multiplication, even though neither $2$ nor $4$ do not have inverses in the ring.

Jane, note that $\varphi:\Bbb R^*\to M_2(\Bbb R), t\mapsto tJ$ satisfies $\varphi(a)\varphi(b)=\varphi(ab)$ if $J=\begin{bmatrix} 1/2& 1/2\1/2 & 1/2 \end{bmatrix}$ (or any idempotent matrix). So, $im(\varphi)$ (with the usual matrix product) is a group, by https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_of_structure.

Absolutely right, the standard product works here.
